# Converting Japanese MS word document to PDF c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

When i am converting Japanese MS Word document to PDF,the content is not rendering. Can I have the solution for this.

Comment: Which converter are you using  ?

Comment: "*Can I have the solution for this.*" - you can't until you'll provide significantly more details. Right now your question is far too broad and can't be answered.

Comment: I am using Spire doc trail version 
http://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/convert-document-containing-japanese-characters-t2951.html